# how to pushback a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, 2d-vector

let's say I have a vector storing vectors of strings. `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> MyVec = { {}, {} }`

I want to use anything equivalent to `.push_back(X)` such that the vector will now look as following: `{ {X}, {} }`.

Does anyone have an idea for a way to solve this?

Comment: `MyVec[0].push_back(x)` or `MyVec.front().push_back(x)`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I honestly didn't even think of that, it was too obvious. thank you anyways!

Comment: Please don't include "solved" in the question. The way you indicate you have found a solution is to mark an accepted answer. It's perfectly acceptable to write an answer to your own question, so I suggest you undelete your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @bolov but I have to wait 2 days to mark it as solved

Comment: Wait 2 days to mark it as solved.

Comment: @bolov that's literally what I did. until then, I added (solved) in the title. I don't see how I could have acted differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyVec[0].push_back(x)` by @MikeCAT worked.